# How can I schedule an elastic job for weekdays only?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I have an elastic job on Azure SQL - I would like it to run Mondays to Fridays every week but not at the weekend.  How can I update the job to reflect this?  All the scheduling stuff seems to be every day, week but you can't customise days that aren't consecutive.  I have been using the update job to update it similar to this:

```
EXEC jobs.sp_update_job
@job_name='Job Name here',
@enabled = 1,
@schedule_interval_type = 'Weeks',
@schedule_interval_count = 1,
@schedule_start_time = '2022-05-13 01:00:00.0000000',
@schedule_end_time = '9999-12-31 11:59:59.0000000'
```

Any ideas how to go about doing this?  Am I stuck with creating a job per weekday and scheduling each job once a week?  Also - please do not suggest using SQL Server agent.  We have a requirement to use Azure SQL and it doesn't have SQL Agent.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To schedule an elastic job for weekdays, set

```
@schedule_interval_type = 'days'
```

Instead of

```
@schedule_interval_type = 'Weeks'
```

Below is the updated job according to the requirement:

```
DECLARE @jobStartDate DATETIME = '<startDate>';
DECLARE @jobEndDate DATETIME = '<endDate>';

-- Check if the start date is a weekend (Saturday or Sunday)
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @jobStartDate) IN (1, 7)
BEGIN
    SET @jobStartDate = DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @jobStartDate) = 7 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, @jobStartDate);
END

-- Check if the end date is a weekend (Saturday or Sunday)
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @jobEndDate) IN (1, 7)
BEGIN
    SET @jobEndDate = DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @jobEndDate) = 7 THEN -1 ELSE -2 END, @jobEndDate);
END

-- Update the job with the modified start and end dates
EXEC jobs.sp_update_job
    @job_name = '<jobName>',
    @enabled = 1,
    @schedule_interval_type = 'Days',
    @schedule_interval_count = 1,
    @schedule_start_time = @jobStartDate,
    @schedule_end_time = @jobEndDate;
```

[image]

You can get the updated job details by executing the command below:

```
SELECT job_name, schedule_interval_type, schedule_interval_count, schedule_start_time, schedule_end_time 
FROM jobs.jobs WHERE job_name = '<jobName>'
```

[image]

.